# python 3 reset game pop up

Tags: python, python-3.x, popupwindow, python-turtle

Forgive the absolute mess of a code, i'm very new to this.
this is a basic avoid falling objects type game, and the problem i'm having is i'm trying to make it so if you 'crash', a pop up will display asking if you want to play again with yes or no buttons.

so far I've got the pop up running and it quits out if no is selected. if yes is selected it either doesn't do anything, or in a different approach i took, it just ran the 'crash' sound again on repeat with the pop up coming back up again instantly.

any one know what i'm doing wrong? i cant seem to find a tutorial of someone making the thing i want

```
#resetting
def restart():
    player_car.goto(-100,-400)
    left.goto(-300, 600)
    mid.goto(-100, 300)
    right.goto(100, 800)
    main


def crashed():
    end = Tk()
    end.iconbitmap('c:/CODEING/test_img/car_icon.ico')
    end.bg = 'black'
    end.title('Restart')
    end.geometry('250x100')

    question = Label(end, text='Would you like to play again?', font=('bold', 12))
    question.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=5)

    yes = Button(end, text='Yes', padx=20, pady=10, font=12, command=restart)
    no = Button(end, text='No', padx=20, pady=10, font=12, command=exit)

    yes.grid(row=3, column=1)
    no.grid(row=3, column=4)

    pad1 = Label(end, padx=10).grid(row=0, column=0)
    pad2 = Label(end).grid(row=2, column=0)

    end.mainloop()


def main():
    global s
    global hs
    #left lane
    left.sety(left.ycor() - left.dy)
    if left.ycor() < -650:
        left.sety(1000)
        winsound.PlaySound('c:/CODEING/Test_sounds/point.wav', winsound.SND_ASYNC)
        s += 10

        if s > hs:
            hs = s
        pen.clear()
        pen.write('''Score= {}
High score ={}'''.format(s, hs), font=('Comic Sans MS',20,'underline'))

    if (left.ycor() <= -300 and left.ycor() >=-480) and (left.xcor() == player_car.xcor()):
        left.dy *= 0
        winsound.PlaySound('c:/CODEING/Test_sounds/car_crash.wav', winsound.SND_ASYNC)
        time.sleep(1)
        crashed()


while True:
    wn.update()
    main()
```

Comment: Hi there! This is a good first question, however, I'd suggest editing out the parts of your code not relevant to the question. In this case, it looks like the "crashed" function is the section of interest.

Comment: In `restart`, there's a line that looks like this: `main`. That does nothing--to call the function, add parentheses after it: `main()`. Make sure to include a [mcve]. The code should still be runnable, even if you remove unimportant parts (like sound effects that you know are working OK). Adding your imports and so forth makes it easier for people to run the code, see the problem, and help.